# How do I convert a list of integers to a string - Python

Tags: python, sorting

So, I'm making a sorting algorithm, that takes a list of integers from a file & saves them to a new file. I've basically gotten it to work, but the only thing that's holding me back from finishing it is that it doesn't let me write the integer list to the new file. So... I try to convert the list to a string, but the code doesn't work correctly & I don't know what messes it up.
Here's the code:

```
from pathlib import Path

content = Path('numbers.txt').read_text()
list_content = content.split()
integer_list = [int(x) for x in list_content]

def selection_sort(list_a):
    indexing_length = range(0, len(list_a)-1)


    for i in indexing_length:
        min_value = i

        for j in range(i+1, len(list_a)):
            if list_a[j] < list_a[min_value]:
               min_value = j

        if min_value != i:
            list_a[min_value], list_a[i] = list_a[i], list_a[min_value]


    str1 = ""  #here is where I think the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it.
    for e in list_a:
        str1 += e

    return str1


file = open('sorted_numbas.txt', 'w')
data = selection_sort(integer_list)
file.write(data)
file.close()
```

edit: The numbers in the file should look like this: 1 4 2 3... and in the output like this: 1 2 3 4... So basically separated by spaces

Comment: You don't really need the sorting algorithm in this question, its about how to convert a list of integers to a string, so `data = [1, 2, 3, ..]` is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close.

Where you suspect you have a problem -- you do.

1. If you want to have space delimited integers again, you need to add them.
2. Likely you get a TypeError with `str1 += e` since `list_a` is a list of ints.

This would fix it. Replace:

```
str1 = ""  #here is where I think the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it.
for e in list_a:
    str1 += e
```

With:

```
str1=' '.join(map(str, list_a))
```

And it should work (not tested...)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the integers to strings and then "join" them with spaces.

```
>>> data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> " ".join(str(i) for i in data)
'1 2 3 4'
```

although you could write this using `map`, generators or list comprehensions are generally the preferred style.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
str1 = ""  #here is where I think the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it.
    for e in list_a:
        str1 += e
```

to

```
str1 = " ". join(map(str, list_a))
```

Comment: this solved the problem! thank you! I will look further into the logic behind this code!